# Build failed after flutter update

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having truble getting my project up after the last flutter update.
I am getting this error:

```
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/reorderables-0.4.2/lib/src/widgets/passthrough_overlay.dart:135:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((Duration duration) {
                       ^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-6.0.1/lib/src/gesture_detector/velocity_tracker.dart:12:9: Error: Superclass has no constructor named 'VelocityTracker'.
      : super(kind);
        ^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am not sure where is the issue here. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

SOLUTION :

first close the project,
then go to the project folder.
Delete all generated files, for example:

- .dart_tool
- .idea
- .build
- .flutter-plugins
- .flutter-plugins-dependencies
- .metadata
- .packages

go and open your IDE

go to File->Invalidate Caches then a dialog will appear click Invalidate and Restart, then invalidate caches and restart

if the IDE is yelling at you after restarting don't worry, close your IDE and re open it.

then Run the necessary commands:

flutter upgrade

flutter clean

flutter pub get

dart pub get